# Efficient Perceptually Important Points (PIPs) algo. in R or Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I try to write an algorithm which finds Perceptually Important Points (PIPs) PIPs in a time series. These are Points which "shape" or "characterize" a time series. It is quite simple. The algorithm connects the first and the last point of the time series and "draws" a line between them. In the next step the algorithm looks for that point in the time series which has the greatest "distance" (the distance can be measured simple by the vertical distance or euclidean distance) to the "imaginary" line. This Point is the next PIP. Now there are two lines. Connecting the first Point with the new PIP and the second line - connecting the new PIP with the last.
The algorithm now does the same again. Checks on both lines: "which point has the greatest distance" -> Set this point as next PIP.

Here is a visualization of the algorithm followed by a pseudo code

[image: Identification of the first 5 PIPs using the vertical distancnce (Fu2008)]

Pseudo code:

```
Function findPIPs(P)
Input: sequence p[1 ..m]
Output: PIPList L[l..m]
Begin
Set L[l] = P[1], L[2] = P[2]
Repeat until L[l ..m] all filled 
Begin
Select point p[j] with maximum distance to the adjacent points in PIPList(L[1] and L[2] initially)
Append P[j] to L
End
Return L
END
```

I tried to implement it in R. But it seems to be completely inefficient. It takes way to much time. Furthermore there is still a small "bug" (sometimes some Points lying exactly on the interpolated line. Hence, the distance is "0" - the algorithm does not account for this problem at the moment).

In the end I think I need to write the code in c++ with Rcpp. Is there a way to make the R code more efficient via vectorization for example?

Here is my R code:

```
# PIPs

# -> Input
## Vector
# <- Output
# PIPs Indiezes

getPIPs <- function(x, y, distance = "EUK") {
    PIPs <- vector("list", 4)
    PIPs[[1]] <- c(1, length(y)) 
  
    for(i in 1:(length(y)-2)) {
        switch(distance,
            EUK = (DISTANCE.F <- EUK.distance.f),
            VD  = (DISTANCE.F <- VD.distance.f ),
        )
    
        PIPs <- helper.f(PIPs, x, y, DISTANCE.F)
    }
  
    return(PIPs)
}

helper.f <- function(PIPs, x, y, DISTANCE.F) {
    t <- sort(PIPs[[1]])
    gesamt <- NULL
  
    for(z in 1:(length(t)-1)) {  
        gesamt <- c(gesamt,DISTANCE.F(x, y, t[z], t[z+1]))
    }

    if(all(gesamt == 0)) return(PIPs)
    else PIPs[[1]] <- append(PIPs[[1]], which.max(gesamt))
  
    return(PIPs)
}

EUK.distance.f <- function(x, y, sI, eI) {
    pointsbetween <- sI:eI

    erg <- 
    sqrt((sI - x[pointsbetween])^2 + (y[sI] - y[pointsbetween])^2) + 
    sqrt((eI - x[pointsbetween])^2 + (y[eI] - y[pointsbetween])^2)
    erg[1] <- 0
    erg <- erg[-length(erg)]

    return(erg)
}

VD.distance.f <- function(x, y, sI, eI) { #Start und Endindex
    erg <- 
    abs(y[sI:eI] - (y[sI] +
        (x[sI:eI] - x[sI]) *
        ((y[eI] - y[sI]) / (x[eI] - x[sI]))
        )
    )
    erg <- erg[-length(erg)]

    return(erg)
}

#visualize
itertivePlotPIPS.f <- function(x, y, z) {
    plot(x, y)
    lines(sort(PIPs[[1]][1:length(x)]), y[sort(PIPs[[1]][1:length(x)])], col  = "azure3")
    lines(sort(PIPs[[1]][1:z]), y[sort(PIPs[[1]][1:z])])
}
```

Run the code with

```
x <- 1:100 # "Time" (x)-axis
y <- sample(1:100) # "Data" y-axis
getPIPs(x, y, "EUK")
```

To visualize the data

```
itertivePlotPIPS.f(x,y,10) # the 10 at the end means "take the first ten PIPs"
```

I hope it is not too confusing. I tried to make it simple.

> References: Fu, Tak chung et al. (2008). "Representing Financial time
> series based on data point importance". In: Engineering Applications
> of Artifcial Intelligence 21.2. F/S, PIIP, pp. 277{300. issn:
> 0952-1976. doi: [http://dx.doi.org/10.
> 1016/j.engappai.2007.04.009](http://dx.doi.org/10.%201016/j.engappai.2007.04.009). url: [http://www.sciencedirect.
> com/science/article/pii/S0952197607000577](http://www.sciencedirect.%20com/science/article/pii/S0952197607000577).

Answer (score 3):

This may be faster, haven't actually tested your code.  I think this works (?!), but probably would need to be tested.  It only checks veritcal distance to the line, more work would need to be done to check euclidean distance to the line.  Mostly it just avoids using explicit for loops which might help to speed up your code.

```
## Some test data
tst <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rnorm(100, 4*sin(seq(1,4*pi,len=100)), 1))
tst <- as.matrix(tst)

pip <- function(ps, interp=NULL, breakpoints=NULL) {
    if (missing(interp)) {
        interp <- approx(x=c(ps[1,"x"], ps[nrow(ps),"x"]), 
                         y=c(ps[1,"y"],ps[nrow(ps),"y"]), n=nrow(ps))
        interp <- do.call(cbind, interp)
        breakpoints <- c(1, nrow(ps))
    } else {
        ds <- sqrt(rowSums((ps - interp)^2))  # close by euclidean distance
        ind <- which.max(ds)
        ends <- c(min(ind-breakpoints[breakpoints<ind]), min(breakpoints[breakpoints>ind]-ind))
        leg1 <- approx(x=c(ps[ind-ends[1],"x"], ps[ind,"x"]),
                         y=c(ps[ind-ends[1],"y"], ps[ind,"y"]), n=ends[1]+1)
        leg2 <- approx(x=c(ps[ind,"x"], ps[ind+ends[2],"x"]),
                         y=c(ps[ind,"y"], ps[ind+ends[2],"y"]), n=ends[2])
        interp[(ind-ends[1]):ind, "y"] <- leg1$y
        interp[(ind+1):(ind+ends[2]), "y"] <- leg2$y
        breakpoints <- c(breakpoints, ind)
    }
    list(interp=interp, breakpoints=breakpoints)
}

constructPIP <- function(ps, times=10) {
    res <- pip(ps)
    for (i in 2:times) {
        res <- pip(ps, res$interp, res$breakpoints)
    }
    res
}

res <- constructPIP(tst, times=5)
plot(tst)
points(res$interp, col="blue", type="l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answer @jenesaisquoi!!

I have made two small improvements:

The first one avoids repeating the last point of the first line on the second one:

leg2 <- approx(x=c(ps[ind,"x"], ps[ind+ends[2],"x"]), y=c(ps[ind,"y"], ps[ind+ends[2],"y"]), **n=ends[2]+1**)

And the second one avoids getting an error when the number of PIPs is high enough to reconstruct the time series perfectly but still numPips <- length(ts). This makes the algorithm to continue searching for pips (until the required number of pips it´s found) but all *distances = 0* so it returns the first PIP (1) and there is no *pips <- newPIP* (because newPIP is 1) so the *adjacentsPIPs* is NA and an error occurs because *no line can´t be interpolated between 2 non na points* in approx. To avoid this error I add the next (no PIP) point as the new PIP until I get the required number of pips:

**if(sum(distances) == 0){ newPIP<- which(!(ts[, 1] %in% pips))[1] }**

```
pip <- function(ts, interp=NULL, pips=NULL) {
  if (missing(interp)) {
    interp <- approx(x=c(ts[1,"x"], ts[nrow(ts),"x"]), y=c(ts[1,"y"],ts[nrow(ts),"y"]), n=nrow(ts))
    interp <- do.call(cbind, interp)
    pips <- c(1, nrow(ts))
  }
  else {
    distances <- sqrt(rowSums((ts - interp)^2))  # close by euclidean distance
    if(sum(distances) == 0){ newPIP<- which(!(ts[, 1] %in% pips))[1] } #news <- which(!(ts[, 1] %in% pips)) newPIP <- sample(news, 1)
    else { newPIP <- which.max(distances) }
    adjacentPIPs <- c(min(newPIP-pips[pips<newPIP]), min(pips[pips>newPIP]-newPIP))

    line1 <- approx(x=c(ts[newPIP-adjacentPIPs[1],"x"], ts[newPIP,"x"]), y=c(ts[newPIP-adjacentPIPs[1],"y"], ts[newPIP,"y"]), n=adjacentPIPs[1]+1)
    line2 <- approx(x=c(ts[newPIP,"x"], ts[newPIP+adjacentPIPs[2],"x"]), y=c(ts[newPIP,"y"], ts[newPIP+adjacentPIPs[2],"y"]), n=adjacentPIPs[2]+1)
    interp[(newPIP-adjacentPIPs[1]):newPIP, "y"] <- line1$y
    interp[(newPIP):(newPIP+adjacentPIPs[2]), "y"] <- line2$y
    pips <- c(pips, newPIP)
  }
  list(interp=interp, pips=pips)
}

constructPIP <- function(ts, times=10) {
  res <- pip(ts)
  for (i in 2:times) {
    res <- pip(ts, res$interp, res$pips)
  }
  res
}
```